# Is there an equivalent to C's __LINE__ macro in Pascal?

Tags: macros, pascal, line-numbers

Is there an equivalent to C's `__LINE__` macro in Pascal? Maybe a function?

```
{ Prints the line number in source file. }
begin
  write(__LINE__)
end.
```

Is supposed to print:

```
3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Free Pascal, you can use: `{$I %LINE%}`

I don't know how portable the construct is between existing compilers.